# Simple Windows 8 Lua engine and IDE?

Tags: windows-8, framework, game-development

I am looking for a free Lua game engine and an accompanying IDE that allows me to compile and create simple games for Windows 8.

The software has to:

- Be simple and use a game framework rather than raw code
- Write apps that are installable on Windows 8 that can run offline

The closest thing I have found is DroidScript for Android, but it only writes apps for Android and uses JavaScript. I also tried Löve but it will not work properly on my Windows 8 tablet and doesn't compile Windows mobile apps.

Comment: I have tried Löve too, but it doesn't make mobile windows apps which is what I am going for.

Comment: Add what you already tried (e.g. Löve) in the main post. JavaScript and Lua are two completely different beasts. Please specify what you want. If you are into HTML5 developments, then there are plenty of engines. Same goes for the IDE and game engine. Completely different things. Moreover, a game engine is typically also a framework.

Answer (score 1):

I know you've tried Löve before, but a similar product with a bit better deployment on Windows is Corona:

https://coronalabs.com/product/

Like Löve it won't do Windows Mobile natively (the CoronaCards setup claims to do that, but I don't have any experience with that to confirm), but it should work a lot better within the Windows 8 environment, and the realtime simulator should make it easy to see effects in real time.